# Add dynamic button to front page from code behind that will call code behind

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, linkbutton

I am trying to figure out how to add, dynamically generated button in the code behind to the front page. The following code generating button in code behind like this:

```
Dim sortLinkButton As New LinkButton()
sortLinkButton.Text = "Click To Sort"
sortLinkButton.OnClientClick = New EventHandler(AddressOf sortLinkButton_Click); <- !!!
```

There is also an error in the last line.

Then I have a div or span or whatever that I can reference using Me.myDIV.innerHTML

I need this button to be click able and when the user clicks on it call code behind function/sub.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your HTML and indicate what you are trying to do? Below is what I'd do if I think I understand what you are trying to do.

You can set `sortLinkButton.OnClientClick` to point at a jQuery ajax function that will call a web method but it would be easier to handle in on client side click function eg

`$('#LinkbuttonClientId').click(function(){  });`

Include the following imports in your back end code

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.Web.Services
```

Add a function to your backend code

```
   <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function WebMethod(value As string) As String
        Try
            Dim ReturnString As New List(Of [String])()
            'Add functionality - if success set first element of ReturnString = 1 else set to 0
            ReturnString.Add("1")
            'Add any other value to return
            ReturnString.Add("another value")
            Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Return serializer.Serialize(ReturnString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Create the same ReturnString variable to return information about an error 
            Dim ReturnString As New List(Of [String])()
            ReturnString.Add("-1")
            ReturnString.Add(ex.Message.ToString + ", " + ex.InnerException.ToString)
            Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Return serializer.Serialize(ReturnString)
        End Try
    End Function
```

Add jQuery to your page (place in `<head></head>`)

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Add a function to called by button click to make ajax call to webmethod

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var WebMethodCall = function(value) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "[page name].aspx/WebMethod",
        data: "{'value' : '" + value + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (obj) {
            try {
                var ret = $.parseJSON(obj.d);
                if (ret[0] > -1) {
                    //run this code after successful return code 
                }
                else {
                    console.log(ret[1])
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e.description || e);
            }
        },
        error: function (ts, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           console.log(ts.responseText)
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

Add a jQuery handler (also in frontend)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#LinkbuttonClientId").click(function(){
        WebMethodCall(value);
        //prevent click from submitting page
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

You could put both js parts in a separate file and include to tidy up. Also 'value' is not necessary but is there to show you how to pass variables into webmethod. It is possible to create the button dynamically in jQuery, if you do that then declare the handler function in the same section of code and use `bind()` or `on()` eg

```
$("#LinkbuttonClientId").on("click", function(){  });`
```

All this is probably overkill for you but it's how I make ajax calls to functions instead of using .net update panels and makes it easy to deal with events from dynamic elements without the need to submit the page.